# При нажатии кнопки не переходит в другое активити

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
         swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

                        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                Intent SecAct2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity2.class);
                startActivity(SecAct); 
                startActivity(SecAct2);
                            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Обработка нажатий двух кнопок (переход между активити) button1 работает, а кнопка button3 не работает (кнопка с идентификатором button2 у меня отвечает за совершенно другой (возврат в предыдущее меню) и находится в другом активити (SecondActivity))

Comment: У вас нет никакого обработчика нажатия на button3,  почему бы оно должно куда то переходить при ее нажатии

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, чтобы клик срабатывал, его надо перехватить и обработать - вы этого для кнопки button2 не делаете.
Во вторых, не в силах постичь вашей логики и преследуемых целей, но вызов подряд двух методов `startActivity()` приведет только к тому, что будет загружена первая активити из вызываемых, до второй дело не дойдет, так как управление перейдет к новой активити (точнее вторая будет запущена при закрытии первой).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(SecAct); 
        }
     });

    swith3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent SecAct2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity2.class);
            startActivity(SecAct2);
       }
    });
   }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnCklickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    swith.setOnClickListener(this);
    swith3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent SecAct;

    switch (v.getID) {
        case R.id.button1:
            SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity2.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(SecAct);
}
```

}