# Android - добавление Activity \ переключение между Activity

Tags: java, android

Работаю в Eclipse. В общем есть переключение между Activity путём нажатия кнопки созданы нужные классы и все прочее, прописан манифест в итоге имеем активити 1 с двумя кнопками на активити 2 и активити 3 ... но при нажатии на любую он перекидывает на активити 2(SecondActivity). Независимо от нажатия на кнопку 1 или кнопку 2 он открывает тока одно и тоже окно (SecondActivity). вот код MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

                    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            Intent SecAct2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity2.class);
                            startActivity(SecAct); 
                            startActivity(SecAct2); 
                                       }
    });

    swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent threActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity2.class);
             startActivity(threActivity);
         }
     });    
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="ru.example.carcar"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
     <activity
        android:name="SecondActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

 </application>

</manifest>
```

---

рано z обрадовался (( ошибок eclips не выдает но в телефоне по прежнему две кнопки открывают одно и тоже окно активити ((...вот снова код может я что то не так скопировал?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button swith = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button swith3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    swith.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

                    {
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)); 
                                       }
    });


    swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity2.class));
         }
     });    
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

p\s ругается на newnew синтактическая ожибка expected поэтому написал new

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите на свой код и подумайте как два подряд вызова ```startActivity(SecAct)``` и ```startActivity(SecAct2)``` могут запустить ```SecAct```?

Comment: Дубликат [этого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513717/177345)

Answer (score 2):

Нужно указывать только один intent на кнопку. У вас из двух произошёл последний, который переходит на ту же активность что и другая кнопка.... Вот правильный код

```
    switch.setOnClickListener(newnew OnClickListener() {
    @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
       }
       });

   swith3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity2.class));
        }
    });    
 }
```

Comment: ругается на newnew синтактическая ожибка expected поэтому написал new а не newnew ошибок не выдало но в телефоне при проверке попрежнему одно и тоже активити открывает

Comment: @aivengos Данный код верен. Если у вас он не работает, то проблема не в этом коде, а либо в кнопках, к которым вы привязываете слушатели, либо в самих классах активити, которые вы вызываете. Так же не лишним будет заметить, что прежде чем писать код, лучше всего изучить язык, на котором вы пишите этот код, программирование методом тыка вас ни к чему хорошему не приведет - newnew просто опечатка, такого оператора в Java не существует, такая вещь никак не должна у вас вызывать затруднение и уж тем более решаться каким то "поэтому написал"